# why Spring basic @Autowired is not working?

Tags: xml, spring, autowired

I'm new in Spring. But trying basic stuff. According to theory I should work, it is not working. I have 2 same beans with different id. I should be able to `@Autowired` with unique id `@Qualifier("PersonBean2")`. But it give error. I have no idea what is wrong where. Please inform me? Thanks!

Where is config  springBeans.xml :-

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean    

 class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.
  AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>


  <bean id="customer" class="com.mkyong.common.Customer" >
    <property name="action" value="buy" />
    <property name="type" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="PersonBean1" class="com.mkyong.common.Person">
    <property name="name" value="mkyong1" />
    <property name="address" value="address 1" />
    <property name="age" value="28" />
</bean>

  <bean id="PersonBean2" class="com.mkyong.common.Person">
    <property name="name" value="mkyong2" />
    <property name="address" value="address 2" />
    <property name="age" value="28" />
    </bean>

   </beans>
```

Customer.java:-

```
public class Customer {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("PersonBean2")
private Person person;
private int type;
private String action;
}
```

Person.java:-

```
public class Person {
private String name;
private String address;
private int age;
}
```

All setter and getter removed.

Test app.java:-

```
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "SpringBeans.xml");

    Customer cust = (Customer) context.getBean("customer");
    System.out.println(cust);
  }
}
```

Error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customer': Autowiring of fields failed; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mkyong.common.Person com.mkyong.common.Customer.person; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.mkyong.common.Person] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [PersonBean1, PersonBean2]
```

Comment: Make sure you used the correct `@Qualifer` the one from spring not the `javax.inject`  one.

Comment: Yes, import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
I think it is the right one.

Comment: You have added the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which, as the name implies, only processes the `@Autowired` annotation. Instead of using the processor directly add `<context:annotation-config />` which adds additional processors which also take `@Qualifier` into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

You have added the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which, as the name implies, only processes the `@Autowired` annotation. Instead of using the processor directly add `<context:annotation-config />` which adds additional processors which also take `@Qualifier` into account.

```
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
```

Another tip prefer versionless schemas `spring-beans.xsd` over versioned schemas `spring-beans-2.5.xsd`.

Answer (score 0):

It should work! It seems that the @Qualifier annotation is not working as expected.

Double check that the @Qualifier annotation is being imported from package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation

Comment: yes imported from org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier